# VIM : Trouble mapping <c-/> and re-selecting visual selection?

Tags: comments, vim, vim-plugin

I am using a **vim plugin** called [tComment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment)

It allows me to comment a line by pressing `gc` or `<c-_><c-_>`

Also, it works on the shortcut `<c-/><c-/>` but the `visual selection` is lost.

So, I tried:

- To make it work on single `<c-/>`
- To retain the visual selection.

**My attempts :**

```
inoremap <c-/> gc
vnoremap <c-/> gc gv
nnoremap <c-/> gc
```

=========

```
imap <c-/> gc
vmap <c-/> gc gv
nmap <c-/> gc
```

=========

```
imap <c-/> gc$
vmap <c-/> gc$ gv
nmap <c-/> gc$
```

=========

```
inoremap <c-/> <c-_><c-_>
vnoremap <c-/> <c-_><c-_> gv
nnoremap <c-/> <c-_><c-_>
```

=========

```
imap <c-/> <c-_><c-_>
vmap <c-/> <c-_><c-_> gv
nmap <c-/> <c-_><c-_>
```

( **Non of the above seems to work** )

**Note:**

1. I have not done any other customizations from my side.
2. My attempts are listed above
3. Installing `tComment` on native `vim` (Ubuntu) lands you to my setup.

Comment: Note that `<C-/>` is the same as `<C-_>`, for historical reasons.

Comment: Even then, it has to be pressed 2 times to comment or uncomment. plus the selection is getting lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have one map (in i, n, & v-mode) that either comments the current line or the visual selection. This is what tcomment's `<c-_><c-_>` map does now (with the exception that you want to maintain the visual selection). In order to use `<c-/>` you have to set g:tcommentMapLeader1 = '' (or some other map, since `<c-/>` seems to be the same as `<c-_>` as echristopherson pointed out) in vimrc and then define your maps for `<c-/>`.

This should work (add these lines to .vimrc):

```
let g:tcommentMapLeader1 = ''
noremap <silent> <c-/> :TComment<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <c-/> :TCommentMaybeInline<cr>gv
inoremap <silent> <c-/> <c-o>:TComment<cr>
```

You might have to replace `<c-/>` with `<c-_>` to make this work. Since you reported that tcomment already worked when typing `<c-/><c-/>`, the `<c-_>` map should work.

Anyway, I'd also recommend to use the operator maps since those fit better the way vim works. I don't think using a single key is still a good idea though.

Comment: As I understand : I can invoke the `g:tcommentMapLeader` with a key mapping as required. So, I didn't exactly understood what you said. Were you able to achieve to the solution ?

Comment: Sorry, but after adding the above - tComment stopped working with `<c-_>` or `<c-/>`. Now, I am looking into `Operator Maps` ( New to me ). But the issue stands un-resolved. :(

Can you try it yourself - if I am messing something else !

Comment: @yugal-jindle: The maps stopped working because `let g:tcommentMapLeader1 = ''` disabled them -- you can use an alternative map here if you want to keep those maps. Could you then please on the command-line type: <c-q><c-/> and check what is inserted on the commandline? (E.g. I cannot type <c-/> on my keyboard, only <c-_>, which probably is the reason why echristopherson meant that they are internally the same. If nothing gets inserted, you might want to use <c-_> in the above example.)

Comment: Sir, I got what you are saying. And expected the following to work :
`let g:tcommentMapLeader1 = 'mm'` `noremap <silent> <c-/> :TComment<cr>` `vnoremap <silent> <c-/> :TCommentMaybeInline<cr>gv` `inoremap <silent> <c-/> <c-o>:TComment<cr>`. Now, `mmmm` works as expected but <c-/> doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Not possible as I am expecting it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ( Works in Gvim but not in Vim )

Comment: Even in `Gvim`, I had to use `<m-/>` instead of `<c-/>`

Answer (score 5):

1. If you want to map keys to another mapping, **you need to use `:map`, not `:noremap`**.
2. For most plugins, this shouldn't be necessary; they usually provide either configuration variables or `<Plug>PluginName...` for that. Read `:help g:tcommentMaps` for instructions for this particular plugin, then place your overrides into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Tried all you said. But didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your attempts. Since tComment uses config variables, you need to define then _before_ the plugin is loaded, e.g. in your .vimrc.

Comment: I am comparatively new to `vim`. I have not done any customizations from my side. You can install `tcomment` and will have the same setup as me.

Comment: I have updated the question with additional findings.

Comment: Your update still says `noremap`, which I told you does not work. And as per 2., rather try something like `:let g:tcommentMapLeaderOp1 = '<C-/>'`

Comment: Also note that the `gc` command wants a `{motion}` after it (to cover the text to be commented), so `gc$` would comment the current line.

Comment: Added other attempts. Please note even after I deleted the mapping from my vimrc - it still seems to work with <c-/> ( 2 times ). But I am unable to find a corresponding binding the plugin or anywhere in the mappings.

Comment: @yugal: The maps are defined in plugin/tcomment.vim.